# Что такое "неоднородность" и "взаимообусловленность" в русском языке?

Tags: терминология

В чем между ними сходство и разница?

Answer (score 2):

**Эту тему удобно рассмотреть на примере бессоюзных сложных предложение (БСП).** Между предложениями, входящими в БСП, могут быть быть однородные,  неоднородные, а также взаимообусловенные   отношения.

**Формально однородность проявляется в одинаковом отношении двух/нескольких  частей к третьему элементу:**

(1) Шумел ветер, гремел гром, лил дождь (в определенный момент времени). Это **однородные** предложения (в составе БСП).

(2) Сверкнула молния, потом полил дождь.  Это **неоднородные** предложения, события происходят в разное время, но они не являются взаимообусловленными, то есть  зависимыми.

(3)Кругом ярко светит солнце – поохотиться ещё можно.  Это **взаимообусловленные** предложения, связанные причинно-следственными отношениями.

**Таким образом, делаем вывод:**

**Сходство**: Неоднородность и взаимообусловленность – это всегда отсутствие однородности частей по отношению к третьему элементу.

**Различие:** Взаимообусловленность – это не только отсутствие однородности частей  по отношению к третьему элементу, но и наличие взаимосвязи этих частей.

**Примечание.** Определение однородности как одинакового отношения двух или нескольких  частей к **третьему элементу** справедливо и для однородных членов, так как однородный ряд всегда раскрывает **общую тему** и к нему можно подобрать **обобщающее слово.**

Answer (score 1):

Неоднородность структурных единиц - разное их качество. Например, неоднородные определения - определения, характеризующие предмет с разных сторон: старая зимняя сказка. Старая - по степени новизны, зимняя - по отношению ко времени года, связи с зимой. В отличие от однородных - одинаковых , характеризующих с одной стороны: пушистые и лохматые.

Неоднородные придаточные предложения относятся к одному слову в главном предложении, но отвечают на разные вопросы:. Я должен поехать в этот город (зачем должен?), чтобы выполнить все задуманное, (почему должен?) потому что дел накопилось очень много.

Взаимообусловленность - взаимное влияние структур друг на друга, их взаимозависимость.

Сложное предложение, у которого части обусловлены не односторонне (когда придаточная зависит от главной), а взаимно, называется сложноподчинённым предложением с взаимообусловленными частями. В таком предложении нельзя выделить главную и придаточную части.

Такие предложения могут иметь:

временное значение (Еще солнце не дошло до половины неба, как все запорожцы собрались в круг. Только успели мы отдохнуть и отобедать, как услышали ружейные выстрелы);

сравнительно-сопоставительное значение (Чем ночь темней, тем ярче звезды);

В сложносочинённых предложениях самостоятельность простых предложений относительна, в предложениях закрытой структуры части представляют собой замкнутый ряд, это всегда две части, структурно и семантически взаимообусловленные, связанные. Это предложения с противительно-сопоставительными и присоединительными отношениями. Вторая часть в них замыкает ряд и не предполагает наличия третьей. Например: Не только Соня без краски не могла выдержать этого взгляда, но и старая графиня и Наташа краснели, заметив этот взгляд (Л. Т.); Он хотел было что-то сказать ему, но толстяк уже исчез.

В БСП неоднородность проявляется в многочленных бессоюзных, то есть тех, которые состоят из трех и, реже, более частей.

По своей структуре и выражаемым в них отношениям такие предложения делятся на две группы: 1) с частями, которые равноправны по отношению друг к другу и выражают перечислительные отношения (предложения однородного состава), и 2) с частями (или, по крайней мере, одной из них), которые не однородны по отношению друг к другу, так что в предложении выражаются не менее двух видов отношений (предложения неоднородного состава).

Последние предложения чаще всего характеризуются тем, что вторая и третья части, вместе взятые (связанные по смыслу и интонационно), относятся к первой части. Значительно реже третья часть относится к двум первым частям, вместе взятым. Например: Все вокруг него опустело: одни перемерли, другие — ушли (Салтыков-Щедрин) (вторая и третья части связаны с первой частью пояснительными отношениями); И Жилин приуныл: видит — дело плохое (Л. Толстой) (вторая и третья части связаны изъяснительно-объектными отношениями; вместе взятые, они связаны причинными отношениями с первой частью); Ну, да это само собой разумеется: душа не яблоко: ее не разделишь (Тургенев) (вторая и третья части связаны следственными отношениями; вместе взятые, они связаны с первой изъяснительно-объектными отношениями); Вы все приставали ко мне: выучи-де нас музыке и французскому диалекту — вот вам и француз, и на фортепья- нах играет... (Тургенев) (первая и вторая части связаны изъяснительно-объектными отношениями; к ним, вместе взятым, прибавлена третья часть—присоединительная).

Взаимообусловленность в БСП выражается причинно-следственными связями. Порядок расположения простых предложений - средство выражения смысловых отношений. Стало прохладно: наступил вечер(второе  указывает на причину,первое на следствие).Наступил вечер - стало прохладно (первое - причина, второе - следствие).

Так что неоднородность структур - это их характеристика с точки зрения структуры, отнесения к разным видам, а взаимообусловленность -  с точки зрения их равного влияния друг на друга.

Сходство в том, что оба термина указывают на отношения между разными структурами.

Comment: А в БСП как выражается неоднородность?

Comment: Сейчас добавлю в ответ